# How to add a navigation case to a JSF project using netbeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans, configuration-files

I have simple JSF2 application running on glashfish 3.1. I want to add a new index page, not change the actual one, but to set a new one that links me to the actual one, I have managed to set the welcome page to **index1** (my new page). xhtml and set my link:

```
<h:commmandLink action="/index/List">
```

But when I test it I  get `Cannot find navigation case matching id...`.

I've set `index1` by:

```
<welcome-file>faces/*index1.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

But when I go to faces-config.xml it shows me the pageflow but no xml tags,
so where do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It solved. needed to remove LIST